# Analyticity of $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ and $\sqrt{z}\sinh(\sqrt{z})$ (Is my logic correct?)

Tags: complex-analysis

Neither $\sinh(\sqrt{z})$ nor $\sqrt{z}$ are analytic, but I would like to know if my rationale below as to their product and ratio being analytic is sound

If we express $z$ as $z=r^2e^{i(\theta+2n\pi)}$ where $\theta = \arg{z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then

$F(z)=\sqrt{z}\sinh(\sqrt{z})= F_n(r,\theta) = \frac{r}{2}e^{i\Bigl(\frac{\theta}{2}+n\pi\Bigr)}
\Bigl[e^{re^{i\Bigl(\frac{\theta}{2}+n\pi\Bigr)}}
-e^{-re^{i\Bigl(\frac{\theta}{2}+n\pi\Bigr)}}\Bigr]$

for $\theta=0$ and $n=0$, we have

$$
\text{Re}[F_0(r,0)] = \frac{r}{2}\Bigl[e^r-e^{-r}\Bigl]
$$

and

$$
\text{Im}[F_0(r,0)] = 0
$$

for $\theta=0$ and $n=1$, we have

$$
\text{Re}[F_1(r,0)] = -\frac{r}{2}\Bigl[e^{-r}-e^r\Bigl]=\text{Re}[F_0(r,0)]
$$

and

$$
\text{Im}[F_1(r,0)] = 0=\text{Im}[F_0(r,0)]
$$

Therefore since the equalities above hold in the limit that $r\rightarrow 0$, $\sqrt{z}\sinh(\sqrt{z})$ is analytic in the complex plane and $z=0$ is not a branch point of  $\sqrt{z}\sinh(\sqrt{z})$

Similarly it can be shown that for $F(z) = \frac{\sinh(\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ that

$$
\text{Re}[F_1(r,0)] = -\frac{2}{r}\Bigl[e^{-r}-e^r\Bigl]=\text{Re}[F_0(r,0)]=\text{Re}[F_0(r,0)]
$$

and using L'Hôpital's rule for the indeterminate limit that
$$
\text{Im}[F_1(r,0)] = 0=\text{Im}[F_0(r,0)]
$$

so that  $z=0$ is not a branch point of  $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ either.

Thanks

Comment: Much simpler: the map $F: z \mapsto z \sinh(z)$ is even, so its Taylor series at $z=0$ only has even coefficients. Now can you find an analytic power series for $F(\sqrt{z})$?

Comment: Not a power series that converges, no!

Comment: If $F(z)=\sum_n a_n z^{2n}$, then $F(\sqrt{z})=\sum_n a_n z^n$

Comment: Starting from Taylor series$$\sinh x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
you get
$$\frac{\sinh \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}$$
which is analytic.  It's the canonical choice to use the same branch of the square-root for either roots.

Comment: Albert, my bad - I was thinking for some weird reason of $\frac{1}{\sqrt(z)}$

Comment: Emacs, could you kindly indulge me by explaining the rationale behind the Taylor series approach. I see that the series for $\sinh x$ is in terms of odd powers of $x$, but that for $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{x)}}{\sqrt{x}}$ is in terms of both odd and even powers of $x$. How does this relate to the function being single-valued as I demonstrated with my approach by a $2\pi$ winding? Thanks!